# Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'users'.ts(2322)

Tags: angular, types, ngrx, reduce

I have the NGRX reducer that has interface and initial state as follows

```
  export interface State {
    data: User[]; sel: User; action: string; done: boolean; err?: Error; }

  export const initialState: State = { data: [],sel: null,action: '', done: false,
    err: null  };
```

This is displaying errors for sel and err in the initialState -Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'users'.ts(2322)
games.reducer.ts(11, 3): The expected type comes from property 'sel' which is declared here on type 'State'

Answer (score 0):

You’ll either have to type the interface of the initial state with property

`sel: User | null`

Or provide a default `sel` within the initialSate which is of `User` type.

### Fuller explanation

Typescript is a layer on top on JavaScript that provides type checking during development. If you declare a variable to be a `string` and  assign it to be a `number` it will complain with error: `Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.`

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEgwCFQfgQnUBLAzqAhqArgF0QG0WwE9RsB7UZACzIHdSqBTUogB2bIDN1QA3NAE6I0AIzyMAUBPHZQAWyIBlbEIB2AcwBclFYg2gAvKADkewsLwA1NHkyNjUqABUqKUIwECyA1HtBO2RmQAYyFWbAA6UAkoADkyXGDmbCZQACk0fkVQxHDSATRVZFZ8RgATUDJVBmYhdSpZN34CCpEcUGCqQvUgmLAU5MDK7nAFZTV1cAkx3X0jACY+0AA9aEcwAPYTVUw5EQ9jJFRVBPRkZER1VVFxUgpiLeNkWfVjCKA)

```
let myString: string = 'initialValue';

// This errors in Typescript. 
myString = 2;

// Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

Similarly this will error for inline typing and assignment:

```
const myString: string = 2;
// Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

### Your code

In your code you tell Typescript to know about a new ‘type’ called State:

```
export interface State {
  data: User[]
  sel: User
  action: string
  done: boolean
  err?: Error
}
```

Any variable *assigned* as type `State` **must** adhere to this type: `action` must be a string, `sel` must be a `User` etc.

You’ve declare a variable to be of type `State` and try to assign it a value that is not of type `State`, so you get your error.

```
export const initialState: State = { 
  data: [],
  sel: null,
  action: '',
  done: false,
  err: null
};
```

Here Typescript errors because you’re giving `sel` value `null` when you’ve said it can only be type `User` which will be some object like `{ name: string etc }`.

(You also cannot assign `null` to `err` as this is either and `Error` or `undefined` due to the optional flag ?)

So you must either change this `null` for a valid value of type `User` or allow `sel` to be `null` by changing the `State` type to allow `sel` to be a `null` value.

In Typescript you can say a variable can be a `User` **or** `null` by using the *union* `User | null`.

```
export interface State {
  data: User[]
  sel: User | null // changed line
  action: string
  done: boolean
  err?: Error
}

export const initialState: State = { 
  data: [],
  sel: null,
  action: '',
  done: false // removed `err`
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdrIN4ChnIhwC2EAXMumFKAOa4C+uuoksiKAymHJDvsgAmvOBQzQA2gF0BmADZjMUZAB9CAVzlzkAeh3IEACzghaEQcjmgIAxGGAB7EBSo1TAwU-LIARg4dyECYC0FAA-BQAolBQDsqMzBAAHgAOcWAGTlTIoMD2cHLcvN5FfAC8OMgeIhTSADSyEAoaWg0Edo7OyADk3W1CXhTwcpi6+lAQxA4AbubIgBgEofOMANxAA)

Comment: Hi, can you please elaborate, sorry I am new to all these.